# Update ItemsControl when XmlDataProvider source is changed

Tags: xml, xaml, rss, itemssource, xmldataprovider

I have an ItemControl Setup to scroll some text from an RSS feed. The rss feed is an external XML document that is being read by the items control, and the contents of the RSS feed are scrolled across the screen like you see on any 24-hour news station.

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="RSS" Source="\...\RSS\RSS.xml" >
    </ResourceDictionary>...

    <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource RSS}, XPath=/rss/channel}" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Items}" >
     <ItemsControl.DataTemplate>
      <!-- data template -->
     </ItemsControl.DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

What I would like to know is how can I refresh the ItemsSource binding, or the content being displayed, when the external XML is changed?

Comment: Have you had any progress yet?

Comment: this got tabled for the time being so no progress has been made. I had looked into using a FileSystemWatcher.Changed event to catch if the file has changed then update the binding.